# Android application info based on it's process name

Tags: android, process

I'm trying to find some info about apps I find using shell's `top` command. All I have is a process name (containing package name). Icon and app name would be perfect. I can't find any suitable soultion via google. Any help would be aprreciated;)

To be preemptive, I use `top` because it's the only way I found to show current processor usage. If someone's familiar with some more API friendly soultion, I'd be grateful.

Example process names I get are:

- `com.android.deskclock` for desktop clock
- `com.creativemobile.DragRacing` for game Drag Racing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here how you get details. Since you have the package name, you can use it to get the corresponding application name, version, and icon.

```
List<PackageInfo> packagess = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
for(int i=0;i<packagess.size();i++) {
    PackageInfo pack = packagess.get(i);
    if ((!getSysPackages) && (pack.versionName == null)) {
        continue ;
    }

  //this is the application name
    pack.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();

  //this is the package name
    pack.packageName;

  //this is the version name
    pack.versionName;

  //this is the version code
    pack.versionCode;

  //this is the application icon
    pack.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
}
```

Comment: To make sure if i understand you correctly, the idea is to loop through the installed packages looking for packages i got from `top` command, right? Sounds delicious, i'll check it in the afternoon, after work;)

Comment: @Moyshe yeah exactly. You could save them in a HashMap or whatever you want.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! Ale the credits are belong to you;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try out below code :

```
private String getTopActivity() {

        ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
        ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(30);
        return ar.topActivity.getClassName().toString();
    }
```

you have to give the permission of get task in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: This is the answer to my second question, right? Because it gives class name instead of app name. Unfortunately, I find it equally useless as my proc name. Moreover, if it's an answer to my second question, are processor stats available somewhere there? Or maybe I am missing something here? Maybe I didn't understand your point?